# Does a javascript "async" function's body execute in any diferent way if it doesn't have an "await" in it?

Tags: javascript, async-await, event-loop

From MDN

> Asynchronous functions operate in a separate order than the rest of the code via the event loop,

However I don't understand what that means for a simple function that doesn't return anything explicitly and doesn't use await at all. Is it in any way useful to declare a function async in this case? Would it be executed at a later time to allow the page to respond for example while it executes? My test shows it's executed synchronously and doesn't defer at all:

```js
async function foo() {
  console.log('Start heavy stuff');
  for (let i = 0; i < 90000000; ++i) {
    Math.random()
  }
  console.log('Fnish heavy stuff')
}

foo();
console.log('All done, synchronously');
```

The logs are shown in the expecterd order, so could there be a use to making this function async in this case? Is this in any way similar to calling this function with a `setTimeout(foo, 0)`?

Comment: No difference unless you have async code in your function.

Answer (score 7):

`async` functions run synchronously until the first `await` or `return` is reached, an error is thrown, or the code execution just runs off the end of the function (as it does in your function). At that point, the function returns a promise.

> Is it in any way useful to declare a function `async` in this case?

Not in that specific case, no. There doesn't seem to be any reason for the function to return a promise, and all of its work is done synchronously as you saw in your test.

> Would it be executed at a later time to allow the page to respond for example while it executes?

No.

There isn't really a good reason to declare a function `async` when it doesn't use `await`. It makes it return a promise, but doesn't do anything else other than that. Maybe if you were going to use it in a promise chain, but...

Here's a slightly different example of how the `async` function runs synchronously:

```js
async function example1() {
    console.log("this is done synchronously");
    await Promise.resolve();
    console.log("this is done asynchronously");
}

console.log("before calling example1");
example1().then(() => {
    console.log("promise from example1 was fulfilled");
});
console.log("after calling example1");
```

That outputs:

```
before calling example1
this is done synchronously
after calling example1
this is done asynchronously
promise from example1 was fulfilled
```

Comment: very well written answer. +1, i guess this can be moved to the dupe target. :)

Comment: @CodeManiac - Thanks. I should have known there was a good dupetarget. I think this is worded specifically enough to this question that I'll leave it here, but...

Answer (score 4):

No, synchronous code like the "heavy" Math.random() loop in your example won't run any differently.

However, the difference is that constructing something like this, which lets other code run, is near-trivial with `async` functions, since all the heavy lifting to make this a coroutine/generator/... happens during transpilation or in the runtime.

```
function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// or maybe:

function continueSoon() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setImmediate(resolve));
}

async function foo() {
  console.log("Start heavy stuff");
  for (let i = 0; i < 90000000; ++i) {
    Math.random();
    if(i % 10000 == 0) await delay(10);
  }
  console.log("Fnish heavy stuff");
}
```